# How do I make a persistence.xml file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I am doing a project that I brought over from a GitHub repo, my project says that I don't have a persistence.xml file and I need to use this file for JPA. I am unsure of how to make a new persistence.xml file in my workspace. My requirements are that I have to use Java 16 and JPA 2.1. I have tried making the persistence.xml file through Properties>Project Facets> and clicking "JPA 2.1" and "Java 16".

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qqwT.png)
of the Problem tab in `Eclipse`.

Comment: How do you make one?  1) Read https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-persistence-xml/.  2) Create a new `persistence.xml` file in the appropriate place in your Eclipse project and start typing ...

Comment: See also https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/task_manage_persistence.htm ... which says that the file should go into the project's META-INF directory, and gives a simple example.  (Ignore the screenshots of the custom editor. They won't work unless you have the relevant plugins in Eclipse.  Just focus on what is says about the file itself.)

Comment: When I right click the META-INF file and try to create a new persistence.xml file it only gives me the design and source tabs, not anything about the general tab, schema tab, etc. Is there any other steps I have to take in order for these tabs to appear?